# Keycloak SAML Metadata: Attributes doesn't returned

Tags: keycloak, saml

In my SAML integration with Keycloak, where I'm the IDP, Keycloak doesn't return the attributes mapped on the client.
There are in the login response, but not in the metadata definition.

I tried url `https://MY_URL/auth/realms/MY_REALM/protocol/saml/descriptor` and I downloaded the files on Keycloak Admin Panel `Clients -> MyClient -> Installation -> Mod Auth Mellon files..` but there aren't metadata.

Could someone help me?

Keycloak version: 12.0.4

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "SAML metadata" do you need?

1.) SAML IDP metadata: `https://MY_URL/auth/realms/MY_REALM/protocol/saml/descriptor` returns SAML IDP metadata

2.) SAML SP metadata: `Clients -> MyClient -> Installation -> SAML Metadata SPSSODescriptor` returns SAML SP metadata

Comment: The Mapping Attributes

Comment: @AngeloC `The Mapping Attributes` is very vague definition, because it is not a part of SAML metadata standard https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf, so I guess you have wrong expectation.